How to Customize Advanced Marker Pin Elements in @angular/google-maps
I'm working with Angular 17 and @angular/google-maps@17.3.3 and would like to customize the appearance of map-advanced-marker pins. According to the Google Advanced Markers documentation, customization options like glyph, scale, and color are available. However, I don't know how to set it using @angular/google-maps@17.3.3.
I tried to apply customization like this:
 <map-advanced-marker
  #markerElem="mapAdvancedMarker"
  [position]="marker.position"
  [content]="{ scale: 1.5 }"
></map-advanced-marker>

This results in the following error:
InvalidValueError: AdvancedMarkerElement: 
`content` invalid: not an instance of Node; and [object Object].

It seems I need to use PinElement object. But I cannot import PinElement from @angular/google-maps.
Is there a correct way to customize the map-advanced-marker in @angular/google-maps? How can I use the PinElement?

I was able to add a custom SVG icon like this: In my .ts file, I created a DOM element for the SVG:
const parser = new DOMParser(); const svgElement = parser.parseFromString(mySvgString, 'image/svg+xml').documentElement; marker.customPin = svgElement;
Then I used this new DOM element as content.
<map-advanced-marker
#markerElem="mapAdvancedMarker"
[position]="marker.position"
[content]="marker.customPin"
>

Gave you an upvote because Google is notoriously lazy and slacking with documentation. Even their AI is presently slacking as Google products have so many versions with breaking changes it cannot differentiate them all.

@CaseyDwayne I was not attentive enough, the marker library loading was in the docs. but thank you!

If I were you, I'd stay away from this package. I tried this package in my project and tested two tasks that had the same function, one by typing legacy and the other by using angular/google-maps. I saw a big performance difference between them. Simply put, when you add a few markers and move the map left and right, it causes lag on the screen. This negatively affects the user experience. From a developer perspective, with Legacy, they have made the tasks that you need to do in seconds very difficult to provide modularity.

My problem was caused by not loading the marker library. I used @googlemaps/js-api-loader to load Google Maps, but I did not specify which libraries to load:
const loader = new Loader({
   apiKey: apiKey,
   version: 'weekly',
   libraries: [],
});

Once I added marker library to load like this: libraries: ['marker'], I was able to start using PinElement:
ts:
 let testPin = new google.maps.marker.PinElement({
       scale: 1.5,
 });

HTML:
<map-advanced-marker
  #mapMarker="mapAdvancedMarker"
  [position]="marker.position"
  [content]="testPin.element"
></map-advanced-marker>

